# How to multiprocess with discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

An example of what I want to do would be something like this

```
i = 0
@bot.command()
async def IncreaseI(ctx):
    global i
    while True:
        i += 1
        sleep(5)

@bot.command()
async def PrintI(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"I: {i}")
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using `time.sleep()`, that's gonna block your whole code, use `await asyncio.sleep()` instead. Second of all it's better to create a task, it's a lot easier to manage, here's how:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

i = 0

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def increaseI():
    global i
    i += 1


increaseI.start() # You can also start in a command

# You can also
increaseI.stop()
increaseI.cancel()
increaseI.restart()
# Read the docs for more methods
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop)